# How can I prevent vertically "squishing" components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I just made my React application responsive for screen widths, but I don't want to go back and make it responsive vertically because I think it looks good how it is. However, there is one issue that I see, and that is that when the screen width shrinks, the components are "squished" vertically.

Is there a way I can globally prevent this, and instead of components changing positions when the screen is shrunk they instead stay where they are?